# Force Close While Clicking on Item in ListView

Tags: kotlin, listview, android-intent

This is my DetailActivity. Is there some thing wrong in it ?? Because there are no errors but the application force close while i click on one og the item in my ListView. I'm sorry i'm new in Kotlin and android.

```
    package com.dicoding.mygithubuser

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.TextView
import de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView

class DetailActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    companion object{
        const val EXTRA_USER = "user_extra"
    }
    private var title: String = "Detai User"
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail)
        setActionBarTitle(title)

        val dataUser = intent.getParcelableExtra<User?>(EXTRA_USER) as User
    
        val imagesrc = findViewById<CircleImageView>(R.id.user_img)
        
        val namesrc = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.get_name)
        
        val unamesrc = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.get_uname)
       
        val locationsrc = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.get_location)
       
        val companysrc = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.get_company)
     
        val followersrc = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.get_followers)
      
        val followingsrc = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.get_following)
      
        val repositorysrc = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.get_reposit)

        imagesrc.setImageResource(dataUser.photo)
        namesrc?.text = dataUser.name
        unamesrc?.text = dataUser.unamw
        locationsrc?.text = dataUser.location
        companysrc?.text = dataUser.company
        followersrc.text = dataUser.follower.toString()
        followingsrc.text = dataUser.following.toString()
        repositorysrc?.text = dataUser.repository.toString()
    }

    private fun setActionBarTitle(title: String) {
        supportActionBar?.title = title

    }
}
```

This is User Class
[User Class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Xtnv.png)

This is the others
[The Other files](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1_x3AWY4DUgvBrV6Hflm2Y8r7UC1G-5M3?usp=sharing)

Comment: What console output are you getting? Can you post your full code or at least also the XML layout file?

Comment: excuse me, i have already edit my post. Could you check it again ? @xjcl

Comment: You're getting a `NullPointerException`. Are you starting this activity from somewhere, or is this the main activity? If you don't pass a `User` as parcelableExtra then the user is `null` and your app crashes.

Comment: Seems like you are adding an `arrayListOf<User>()` as parcelableExtra in MainActivity but then casting it to `User` in DetailActivity. You should try just passing a single example `User` instead of the whole list.

Comment: I change arrayListOf<User>() to User(). It can move to another activity but the data doesn't emerge @xjcl

Comment: What error message do you get on the command line? Can you upload an updated minimal example?

Comment: i didn't get any error message tho, But on the folder that i shared above, there is a file of logcat's contents @xjcl

Comment: The error messages you are getting are the long tracebacks. `Didn't find class "android.view.View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener"` and `java.lang.IllegalStateException: No current tap-and-pay account`. Do these help you?

Comment: Thank you very much for your guidance. it's been solved. Anyway, i had not log the data so that's why it didn't emerge.